# BoltzTraP : getting the error 'segmentation fault'

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-espresso, wien2k, boltztrap

I am doing some calculations with Quantum Espresso and wanted to calculate the electronic conductivity of my 2D nanosheet using BoltzTrap. After the successful creation of the BoltzTraP.def and the associated files using ****qe2boltz.py****, I tried to perform the next step which is running the command

> $ x_trans BoltzTrap

And this error appeared:

```
> ================ BoltzTraP vs 1.2.5 ============= 
> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
> Backtrace for this error:
> #0  0x7fa495b3bbd0 in ???
> #1  0x7fa495b3ae25 in ???
> #2  0x7fa495810d5f in ???
> #3  0x559a9795f54b in boltztrap   at /home/user/Documents/boltztrap-1.2.5/src/BoltzTraP.F90:297
> #4  0x559a9794f5ce in main    at /home/user/Documents/boltztrap-1.2.5/src/BoltzTraP.F90:20 Segmentation fault
> 0.2u 0.0s 0:00.23 95.6% 0+0k 0+144io 0pf+0w
```

**What is the source of this issue and how can I solve it?**

**I appreciate the help**

Comment: It's most likely a bug in the code, but could be a problem with the installation or something like a compiler bug. We can't tell with what you have provided. As long as they are not too long editing the question to include the input files would be a first step.

Comment: How many bands and interpolated k-points do you have? IIRC BoltzTraP 1 puts some data on the stack, an area of the computer's memory which typically has a lower usage limit. You could try setting the stack usage to "unlimited" and rerunning; e.g. in a bash shell the relevant command is "ulimit -s unlimited"